# Examples of when PCA would be preferred over NMF

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, non-negative-matrix-factorization

**What are some specific examples of when PCA should be used instead of NMF?**

PCA is a widely used method for dimension reduction in data science, machine learning, and bioinformatics. NMF is also a popular method for dimension reduction, much like PCA, and can be used for many of the same types of analyses (e.g. graph-based clustering, trajectory inference, a denoised embedding for reduction with UMAP, etc.) but with very different theoretical and practical characteristics:

- PCA components are orthogonal while NMF factors are colinear. Orthogonality means that information in a given component is dependent on information in preceding components. Colinearity means that factors are additive in parallel, and parts of the whole.
- PCA values are signed while NMF values are >= 0. This means PCA fits to missing signal while NMF imputes signal.
- PCA is exact while NMF is approximate (requires random initialization). However, PCA is only exact within a dataset and components are components are rarely comparable between datasets, while NMF can isolate factors that are similar in independent models with substantial differences.
- PCA explains variation, NMF explains additive signal. PCA is essentially sequential normalizations of data along axes of variation while NMF isolates distinct and interpretable signals within the data.
- It is difficult to estimate an appropriate number of PCs to use, while NMF almost always has an optimal rank that can be determined by cross-validation.

I have developed NMF and PCA implementations from scratch, but find myself preferring NMF for almost every problem I address. Most of my data is non-negative count data or some normalization of count data, but this leaves me wondering when PCA is actually more useful than NMF. Given it's historical prescience, wide use (or abuse), and mathematical utility, there must be some practical applications where PCA, but not NMF, is the go-to method?  I have to teach a class on data mining, and I'd like at least one or two examples where PCA is both appropriate to use and the preferred method.

Comment: Re your list of characteristics: Much of this looks confused to me or at least using nonstandard terminology. For example, collinear factors are statistically dependent, not independent. Neither PCA nor NMF imply how to impute a missing value, and I don't know what you mean by "upward" - from where? What result does this refer to: "NMF can capture robust signals across similar datasets" - I'm not aware of anything in this respect that NMF can do and PCA can't. "NMF isolates generating processes" - unless you assume a data generating model, this cannot be taken for granted.

Comment: Dimension reduction routines (there are dozens) are rarely an end in themselves but a single step in a multi-step process. If the results are of interest then PCA, as with most linear methods, lends itself to their commonsense interpretability. This is valuable when explaining things to nontechnical audiences. In addition, PCA does not perform well with mixtures of variables. Continuously distributed information with few outliers work best. Introducing discrete data, e.g., 0,1 dummies, will result in heavily biased results. NMF may be more flexible in this regard.

Comment: @ChristianHennig thanks for the great critiques!  Question edited for clarity and language.  As an example where "NMF can capture robust signals across similar datasets" and not PCA, one might perform dimensional reduction using NMF or PCA on a single-cell transcriptomics experiment from lung and skin -- very different, but with some overlapping cell types.  PCA components will not at all align, while a subset of NMF factors will (i.e. those factors describing information about cell types in common).  This is simply a feature of orthogonality vs. colinearity.

Comment: I'm not sure everybody knows what NMF is; explaining abbreviation is preferable.

Comment: The list still looks like a sales pitch for NMF with a number of unclear, questionable, and imprecise statements. "Colinearity means that factors are (...) parts of the whole"?? "This means PCA fits to missing signal while NMF imputes signal" - "This means" seems nonsensical, and neither is it clear what "fits to missing signal" means. The last statement is relative to what dimension reduction is used for, and statements in between sound as if they are backed up by theory but I'm not so sure they are.

Comment: Presenting PC scores with zero mean is just a strong convention. You can use any linear rescaling and preserve the information. That said, I can't see that this convention bites in any practical sense, unless through the fact that you may need to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd normally prefer PCA for low-d (usually 2-d) data visualisation, as orthogonal components are more intuitive in this respect.

I also suspect that PCA will usually work better for dimension reduction of the x-space in linear regression, because collinearity is unhelpful in regression, although I normally use neither for this task (I have seen data in which Principal Components Regression did a pretty good job, but even there something else such as Partial Least Squares could be found that is slightly better using cross-validation for comparison; I don't think NMF would've been any good in these situations though).

Answer (score 1):

NMF stands for "nonnegative matrix factorization", which means that your input data must be nonnegative. The factorization you get is also nonnegative, so you don't have to worry about the interpretability of your results compared to PCA that generally requires other post processing steps to interpret the results. If your data are negative, NMF is not suited then.

The NMF optimization problem is flexible, you can add additional constraints and regularization terms to the objective function to specify the solution you want. There are many NMF extensions and variants among them orthogonal NMF, which aims to produce a unique solution.

Numerous studies have demonstrated the effectiveness of NMF over PCA.